# Pop up content in silverlight that appears over other controls

Tags: silverlight, xaml, user-controls

I have a Silverlight user control that is a textbox with a search button attached to it. When the search button is clicked then the grid with the search controls is made visible. The search controls are in a grid that is located in a canvas with the search button. The grid is collapsed until the search button is clicked. The issue that I am having is that the search grid doesn't appear above all other controls. When my control gets focus I set the Canvas.ZIndex property to 100 which caused it to appear above MOST other controls, but there are still some buttons on the page that the pop up doesn't appear over. Any ideas?

Comment: Any reason why you are not using the Silverlight Toolkit (http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) it contains a very nice ChildWindow control?

Comment: @Erno A child window is not what is needed here, think of the date picker control... how you click on a button and then the calendar pops up that you can pick the date from - that is the type of popup I'm looking for.

Comment: OK, that wasn't clear to me. Perhaps you should re-use the functionality of a ComboBox's itempanel; they always appear on top of the rest.

Comment: :) I bet there are people who know about the popup, they just didn't read this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out about the Popup class: [System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

This allows for content wrapped in a popup tag to be "popped up" over all other content... exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your control at the very bottom of the XAML. The order that it appears in the XAML affects it Z-Index positioning.

Comment: ZIndex on the control doesn't seem to be the way to fix this. The control is inside of a form so it can't go at the bottom of the xaml.